# check if specific field in all rows is empty in a grid field

Tags: grid, table

Trying to check if all the last two fields are empty in all rows in a grid.

Right now code is checking each row:

```
{if page_minutes_table:total_rows > 0}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Meeting Name</td>
                <th>Minutes</td>
                {if page_minutes_table:document_2 != "" && page_minutes_table:document_3 != ""}
                <th colspan="2">Additional Documents</td>
                {/if}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {page_minutes_table}
            <tr>
                <td>{page_minutes_table:meeting_name}</td>
                <td>{if page_minutes_table:minutes_document}<a href="{page_minutes_table:minutes_document}" target="_blank">Download Minutes</a>{if:else}coming soon{/if}</td>
                {if page_minutes_table:document_2 != "" && page_minutes_table:document_3 != ""}
                    <td>{page_minutes_table:document_2}</td>
                    <td>{page_minutes_table:document_3}</td>
                {/if}
            </tr>
        {/page_minutes_table}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do - in your example code you appear to want to display all entries in the grid field, and have a heading included if there are downloadable documents available for an entry.  The only way to do this is to loop through every row in the grid field.

I think you are asking if there is a way to get the information about how many rows in the table don't have either document_2 or document_3 defined without having to loop through all the entries.  One way would be to use the [`search:column_name`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/grid.html#search-column-name) parameter in your grid tags.

The [`search:column_name`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/grid.html#search-column-name) parameter limits the results generated by a tag to just those entries within the entire (in this case grid) field that meet the criteria.  This is helpful where you only want to work with a subset of entries, but here you could use it just to flush out a `total_rows` count for the search - thusly:

```
{page_minutes_table search:document_2="not IS_EMPTY" search:document_3="not IS_EMPTY"}
   {if page_minutes_table:total_rows}There are {page_minutes_table:total_rows} entries that have both{/if}
{/page_minutes_table}
```

HTH